Who does "she" refer to in this excerpt from "The Reconstruction of Religious Thought in Islam"?
This is an excerpt from The Reconstruction of Religious Thought in Islam by Allama Muhammad Iqbal:

It cannot, however, be denied that Ghazali's mission was almost
apostolic like that of Kant in Germany of the eighteenth century. In Germany rationalism appeared as an ally of religion, but she soon realized that the dogmatic side of religion was incapable of demonstration. The only course open to her was to eliminate dogma from the sacred record. With the elimination of dogma came the utilitarian view of morality, and thus rationalism completed the reign of unbelief.
Full text here

The use of "she" in this sentence is confusing. Does it refer to Kant or Ghalazi, both of whom are male. Could it be personification of "rationalism"?

BTW, the word is "antecedent": "rationalism" is the antecedent of "she".

As you said, Kant and Ghalazi are male. I believe you are right - 'she' is neither of them, and is the personification of something.
You'll see that rationalism is said to be an 'ally' of religion. Two abstract concepts cannot literally be allies, so this is an example of personification and could well indicate that 'she' refers to rationalism. In English, the feminine gender tends to be used the most in personification, in particular for abstract concepts, such as nature and justice.
It has been suggested in a comment that 'she' could also refer to Germany. Indeed, the feminine gender is often used in the personification of countries. However, Germany is an exception to that. While many counties are referred to as the 'motherland' by their citizens (Russia, Spain and Greece, for example), for linguistic, historical and cultural reasons, Germans personify their country as male and call it the fatherland. For this reason, and the fact that you mention finding it personified in other philosophical works, I think 'rationalism' is the correct answer.

As a native speaker, I find the personification and gendering of 'rationalism' odd and awkward.

But of course I offer that observation not because critique of Iqbal’s style is relevant here, but rather as well-meant information that students of English may find helpful in their own use of personification.  The message is that this use by Iqbal strikes me as a poor model for how to use personification in one’s own writing.

@PaulTanenbaum I agree, it isn't relevant to offer any observation about the source material in a comment on an answer. Comments on answers should be limited to constructively helping make the answer better.

@Astralbee - are you suggesting that my comment, or a fuller version, would have been more usefully placed under the original question?

For the record, I have just found another personification of "rationalism" in another book, p.368. I guess it is not uncommon in philosophy.

@MichaelHarvey If you think the comment would help improve the question in some way.

I think "she" in this case refers not to rationalism but to Germany, the nation.  It's not at all uncommon to refer to a country using feminine pronouns.

@DarrelHoffman You should post that as a separate answer.

@DarrelHoffman I think you're right. Even if you personify rationalism, how would it "eliminate dogma from the sacred record". This is something a society can do.

@DarrelHoffman while you're correct that many countries are referred to using feminine pronouns, Germany is an exception. Since at least the 13th century it has been the fatherland, not the motherland.

Note the last sentence in the snippet: "With the elimination of dogma came the utilitarian view of morality, and thus rationalism completed the reign of unbelief". This establishes that (a) rationalism is a personified actor which is reported to do things (b) "thus" is used to state that rationalism is the one who eliminated dogma, which then links back to the earlier statement of "The only course open to her was to eliminate dogma", which in turn links back to "but she soon realized [...]" which is used to explain why rationalism chose to eliminate dogma.

@Flater - I think your most recent comment helps me elucidate the uneasy feeling I had ever since reading the quoted text in the original question. That feeling is that the ideas of Islamic and 'rational' thought are portrayed in a rather cartoonish and simplified way, a bit like a tract. This review does nothing to dissuade me from that.

A quote: "Even those who are willing to entertain metaphysical speculation should be aware that this is not a systematic philosophical text. All the central claims of the book are simply asserted (there is rarely any detailed argument showing why they are correct) and the historical views are very early 20th century, with the ghosts of Spengler and countless lesser writers hovering in the background. Entire cultures and historical epochs are summed up in ex-cathedra pronouncements".

@Astralbee - Before the question comes before the lower House in France I would like those discussing it to be able to say: "At least Great Britain is prepared to ratify." Then we should have Belgium, France and Great Britain in agreement. As for Germany, she has not been altogether idle in this matter.  Arthur Hayday MP, Hansard, 28 February 1927. As for Germany, she has devoted all of her resources during the last seven years to the creation of a tremendous military machine André Géraud ('Pertinax'), Foreign Affairs, July 1940.

@Student - you had to dig deep for a personification of rationalism, to the Presbyterian Quarterly for April, 1875. I think that calling the matter in that publication 'philosophy' is straining the meaning of that word a little.

Yup, Occam's razor; the antecedent is right there in the preceding clause. Meanwhile @MichaelHarvey I think it has a lot to do with the fact simply that this was written in 1930. It's been common enough in past centuries to personify abstract concepts, often as female (justice, fate, Brittania—but c.f. Albion). It was probably a bit dated already in 1930, and is just more so now.

@AndyBonner - yes, I agree, dated. I was hoping to counteract any suggestion that Germany was/is traditionally personified in the way we are discussing as 'male', and I feel I have done that, and only turned up rather elderly examples. Interestingly, I have found exact-text instances of "as for France, she has" right up to 2018.
